# Get Direct3D device from Direct2D render target

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct2d

I'm using Direct2D to render my user interface.

What I would like is to be more easily able to profile my ui rendering (since I'm using several panels using Graphics debugger is a bit cumbersome).

Since I know that Direct2D uses a Direct3D device (exactly d3d11 device using 10_0 feature level) under the hood, I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve either a ID310Device or ID3D11Device instance from ID2D1RenderTarget or ID2D1Factory object.

In that case I would easily be able to attach a timestamp query on the BeginDraw/EndDraw calls.

I tried several QueryInterface calls, but none of them have been sucessful so far.

Comment: I already checked this link, but sadly it doesn't provide a solution for my use case, there's nothing there to allows to retrieve d3d device from render target.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But it can be done the other way around. Setup D3D and render D2D in it. On Windows 8.1 you can interop D3D11 with D2D1 easily.

Comment: You're pretty much right, I went that way in my render panels, create a dx11 swapchain and assign a d2d device context to the surface. Was so easy it's even embarassing I didn't do that ove before ;) Now works like a charm, can mix dx11 render and run queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting undocumented secret is that any `ID2D1RenderTarget` you get from `ID2D1Factory` will also be an `ID2D1DeviceContext` (it seems to be intentional from what I've gathered, just *accidentally* undocumented?). Just call `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` to snag it. From there you can toy around with methods like `GetDevice()` and `GetTarget()`. If you can get the target then you may be able to weasel your way to obtaining the `IDXGISurface` which supports `IDXGIDeviceSubObject::GetDevice()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174529(v=vs.85).aspx (I haven't verified this part)

And in Win10 it looks like `ID2D1Device2` gives you precisely what you want: `GetDxgiDevice()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn917489(v=vs.85).aspx . So in that case, your `ID2D1RenderTarget` is cast to an `ID2D1DeviceContext` via `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`, and then you get an `ID2D1Device` via `ID2D1DeviceContext::GetDevice()` and then cast it to an `ID2D1Device2` via another call to `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`.